# ¿Cómo invertir el orden de las cifras un número?

Tags: javascript

Esto es lo he hecho

```
function suma(valor1,valor2){
    resultado =valor1 + valor2;
    document.write (reverseString(' El resultado es:' + resultado));
}

var num1 = parseInt(prompt('introduzca un valor'))
var num2 = parseInt(prompt('introduzca un valor'))
suma(num1,num2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si me Funciono de esta manera

```
function suma(valor1,valor2){
        resultado =valor1 + valor2;
        document.write(' El resultado es:' + reverseString(resultado.toString()));
       }



       function reverseString(s){
    return s.split("").reverse().join("");
}

var num1 = parseInt(prompt('introduzca un valor'))
        var num2 = parseInt(prompt('introduzca un valor'))

        suma(num1,num2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Si lo único que quires es invertir tu variable `resultado`, solo deberías pasarle esa variable al método `reverseString()`. Además tienes que convertir tu variable al tipo String antes de poder aplicar la función.

Prueba con esto:

```
function reverseString(s){
    return s.split("").reverse().join("");
}

reverseString(resultado.toString());
```